# Drawing over parts of a node with rounded corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rounded-corners

On the left I have created two nodes (`Zero Node` in blue and `One Node` in gray) and would like to draw over the existing path from A-B-C-D (including the notches).

On the right is my attempt drawn in red, which isn't quite right.

How can I do a better job at this and is there an easier way to do this?

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{Node Style Gray/.style={
    rounded corners, 
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=2cm,
    draw=gray,
    ultra thick,
    inner sep=0pt,
    opacity=0.5, 
}}
\tikzset{Node Style Blue/.style={
    rounded corners, 
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=2cm,
    draw=blue,
    thick,
    inner sep=0pt,
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (Zero) at (0,0) {0};
\node (One)  at (0,3) {1};
\node [Node Style Blue, fit={(Zero)           }] (Zero Node) {};
\node [Node Style Gray, fit={(Zero Node) (One)}] (One Node)  {};
    
\node [right] at (Zero Node.north east) {A};
\node [left]  at (Zero Node.north west) {B};
\node [left]  at (One Node.north west)  {C};
\node [right] at (One Node.north east)  {D};

%% ------------------------------------------- My attempt
\draw [rounded corners, red, ultra thick] 
       (One Node.north east)
    -- (One Node.north west)
    -- ([yshift=-1.0ex]One Node.north west |- Zero Node.north west)
    -- ++(0,1.0ex)
    -| ([yshift=-1.0ex]Zero Node.north east -| One Node.north east)
    --cycle
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply neglect the widths of the lines. Since the gray and blue lines come with different widths, I cannot provide a *perfect* overlap with simple rounded corners. Otherwise just subtracting the line widths seems to work. To this end, I introduce a `fake fit` node with negative `inner sep`, whose value is determined by the `line width`s of the fitted node and the one drawn afterwards (red), of course divided by two. **UPDATE**: In a second picture, I add a fit of the lower two arcs with elliptic arcs, where the "ellipticity" is governed by a calculable difference of line widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{Node Style Gray/.style={
    rounded corners, 
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=2cm,
    draw=gray,
    ultra thick,
    inner sep=0pt,
    opacity=0.5, 
}}
\tikzset{Node Style Blue/.style={
    rounded corners, 
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=2cm,
    draw=blue,
    thick,
    inner sep=0pt,
}}
\tikzset{fake fit/.style={draw=none,inner sep=-1pt,fit=#1}}
% 1pt = 0.5 * (0.4pt+1.6pt), 
% where 0.4pt is the ordinary line width and 1.6pt is ultra thick line width

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (Zero) at (0,0) {0};
\node (One)  at (0,3) {1};
\node [Node Style Blue, fit={(Zero)           }] (Zero Node) {};
\node [Node Style Gray, fit={(Zero Node) (One)}] (One Node)  {};

\node (A) [right] at (Zero Node.north east) {A};
\node (B) [left]  at (Zero Node.north west) {B};
\node (C) [left]  at (One Node.north west)  {C};
\node (D) [right] at (One Node.north east)  {D};


\node[fake fit=(One Node)] (Fake One Node) {};
%% ------------------------------------------- My attempt
\draw [rounded corners, red, ultra thick,opacity=0.5] {\pgfextra{\typeout{\the\pgflinewidth}}}
       (Fake One Node.north east)
    -- (Fake One Node.north west)
    -- ([yshift=-1.0ex]Fake One Node.north west |- Zero Node.north west)
    -- ++(0,1.0ex)
    -| ([yshift=-1.0ex]Zero Node.north east -| Fake One Node.north east)
    --cycle
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}~%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (Zero) at (0,0) {0};
\node (One)  at (0,3) {1};
\node [Node Style Blue, fit={(Zero)           }] (Zero Node) {};
\node [Node Style Gray, fit={(Zero Node) (One)}] (One Node)  {};

\node (A) [right] at (Zero Node.north east) {A};
\node (B) [left]  at (Zero Node.north west) {B};
\node (C) [left]  at (One Node.north west)  {C};
\node (D) [right] at (One Node.north east)  {D};


\node[fake fit=(One Node)] (Fake One Node) {};
%% ------------------------------------------- My attempt
\pgfmathsetmacro{\arcX}{1.0ex+0.5*(1.6pt-0.4pt)}
\typeout{\arcX}
\draw [red, ultra thick,opacity=0.5] 
       (Fake One Node.north east)
     -- (Fake One Node.north west)
    -- 
    ([yshift=-1.0ex]Fake One Node.north west |- Zero Node.north west)
    arc(180:90:\arcX*1pt and 1.0ex)
    -- ([xshift=-\arcX*1pt]Zero Node.north east -| Fake One Node.north east)
    arc(90:0:\arcX*1pt and 1.0ex)
     --cycle
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]